# Como fazer o build de um jar mesmo que o projeto tenha um erro de compilação?

Tags: java, maven

Estou começando o processo de automatizar os builds da nossa aplicação, e no projeto tem algumas classes com erro de compilação.

Apesar de alguns erros de compilação, a aplicação está funcionando bem. Terei que fazer uma força tarefa, para remover os erros de compilação mas o projeto é muito grande e eu gostaria de fazer isso apenas futuramente.

No momento eu gostaria que o Maven criasse o JAR mesmo que haja erros de compilação.

Fiz uma alteracao no meu `pom.xml` para que o build não falhe, mesmo que haja erros de compilação:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

no entanto, quando executo `maven package` é criado um JAR vazio, sem nenhuma classe. 
Como fazer para o maven criar o JAR com as classes que puderam ser compiladas mesmo que existam outras classes com erros de compilação?

Comment: mvc clean package - P release -U?

Comment: Porque você quer excluir classes com erro de compilação ? De qualquer forma não tem o porque você ter um .jar com classe faltando, existe dependências entre as classes e muito outros fatores. Caso você consiga isso, onde você vai usar um arquivo desse ? Por favor Explique um pouco melhor seu contexto para poder ajudar melhor. Att

Comment: Você quer montar um jar faltando classes e espera que funcione, como isso? Sua pergunta não parece fazer sentido, por favor explique melhor onde quer chegar.

Comment: Eu gostaria apenas que o JAR seja criado, mesmo que contenha classes com erro de compilação. Apesar de alguns erros de compilação, a aplicação está funcionando bem. Terei que fazer uma força tarefa, para remover os erros de compilação mas o projeto é muito grande e eu gostaria de fazer isso mais para frente.

Comment: `Apesar de alguns erros de compilação, a aplicação está funcionando bem(...)` Tenha medo, tenha muito medo do que o futuro guarda para você e sua força tarefa quando tiverem que manter a base de código.

Comment: @JosuéEduardo alterei a pergunta

Comment: @Renan O projeto é legado, estamos começando a automatizar o build, que antes era feito diretamente pelo eclipse. Vamos remover os erros de compilação, mas a prioridade atual é automatizar o JAR da forma que está. Um passo de cada vez.

Comment: Cara, ou a app tem erro ou não ! é simples assim, colocar .jar / .war / .ear pra rodar com qualquer erro de compilação é loucura. Mesmo se for erro de sintaxe não verificada no xml. Primeiramente conserte e faça um merge dos "erros" do projeto legado, pra depois pensar em automatizar o build. Ou verifique a gestão do projeto, pq estão colocando a carroça na frente dos bois =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isso não seja possível. O build vai passar pelas fases do ciclo de construção do Maven, e quando chegar no `compile` vai simplesmente parar... e como por padrão o `compile` é executado antes do `package`, não seria possível você criar o jar desta maneira.

Pelo que entendi você tem uma aplicação gigante com erros de compilação, mas mesmo assim você quer criar um jar, porque as partes sem erro de compilação estão funcionando.

Já trabalhei uma vez em um projeto legado assim. O que fiz na época, foi criar outro diretório de sources. Se você tem o src/main/java, você pode criar um legacy-src e mover as classes com erro pra lá. Daí no seu IDE você inclui esse diretório no build e vai arrumando aos poucos, mas o importante é que o que estiver no src/main/java esteja OK.

Dessa maneira o Maven vai fazer o build normal, gerar o jar etc. E os arquivos no legacy-src não serão utilizados.

Ou se preferir ainda (ou se precisar para versionar, etc) você pode criar outro projeto e ir arrumando aos poucos as classes também.